# Call Android service from Website?

Tags: android, service

My question is, Is there any way or is it possible to call Android service and make it start running from website like if I have website that I want to retrieve data from Android device by calling service already installed in that device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use service to periodically check for new information. But to directly do anything from the server you need to push notification. For that check the http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/ and http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html I'm also using UrbanAirShip (but it still using C2DM).